# Is the continuity correction for binomial random variables always an improvement?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a binomial random variable with parameters $n=90$ and $p=1/3;$ i.e. $S_n \sim$ Bin$(1/3,90).$ I want to estimate the probability:
$$P(S_n \leq 20).$$
To that end:
$$P(S_n \leq 20) = P\left( \frac{S_n -np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{20 -np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \right) \approx \Phi(-2.236)\approx 1-\Phi(2.24) =0.0125$$
Applying the continuity correction yields:
$$P(S_n \leq 20.5) = P\left( \frac{S_n -np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{20 -np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \right) \approx \Phi(-2.124)\approx 1-\Phi(2.12) =0.017$$

The actual probability can be calculated exactly [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=binomial%20probability&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22BinomialProbabilities%22%2C%20%22x%22%7D%20-%3E%2221%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22BinomialProbabilities%22%2C%20%22n%22%7D%20-%3E%2290%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22binomial%20probability%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Formula%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22BinomialProbabilities%22%2C%20%22p%22%7D%20-%3E%221%2F3%22) and it is
$$\approx 0.014625$$
So the errors are $0.002125$, which is $14.5 \%$ for the non-continuity corrected, and $0.002375,$ which is $16.2 \%$ for the continuity corrected. This implies that the continuity is *worse* in this case.

Comment: As you has shown, it is not always an improvement.

Comment: My intuition is that it's worse the further $p$ is from $1/2$. Not sure about that, though.